# Generate private/public pair key using ECC : elliptic curves

Tags: cryptography, elliptic-curve

I working on little ECC crypto problem.

The goal is to write a program in C or bash, which will take as input a hash composed of 128 characters in hexadecimal
`(Example: 8A9A35145C4EA5260DF9972C804FE2D3F9F3D7A2AC01A6BEB21C82BB30957B3952273AC9166B90C1207347A925780F84A1D2359E7AA05201C674D2B9746FCA07)`

and which will generate from the `input hash` a private key and a public key of type **Elliptic Curve** and display the key pair generated.

Can someone clarify for me the problem. I can't understand why we need a hash(or any string) to generate a pair key, as I found In many online solution like [this one](https://github.com/esxgx/easy-ecc) ther's no need to give a hash. Maybe is it a parphase ? Maybe It's the curve key or somthing similar.

I think all we need is to do something like this for the private key:
`openssl ecparam -genkey -noout -out myprivatekey.pem`

and for the public key generation:

`openssl -ec  -in myprivatekey.pem -pubout -out mypublickey.pem`

The question is : why we need an input a hash composed of 128 to generate our pair keys? Is it a passphrase for security reason? how made the trick with openssl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact this is my own code, you can improve it and edit the solution bellow:

```
// gcc -Wall ecdsapubkey.c -o ecdsapubkey -lcrypto
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int main()
{
     EC_KEY *eckey = NULL;
     EC_POINT *pub_key = NULL;
     const EC_GROUP *group = NULL;
     BIGNUM *start;
     BIGNUM *res;
     BN_CTX *ctx;

     start = BN_new();
     ctx = BN_CTX_new(); // ctx is an optional buffer to save time from allocating and deallocating memory whenever required

     res = start;
     BN_hex2bn(&res,"8A9A35145C4EA5260DF9972C804FE2D3F9F3D7A2AC01A6BEB21C82BB30957B3952273AC9166B90C1207347A925780F84A1D2359E7AA05201C674D2B9746FCA07");
     eckey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);

     group = EC_KEY_get0_group(eckey);
     pub_key = EC_POINT_new(group);


    printf("private key : "); BN_print_fp(stdout, res); printf("\n");
    EC_KEY_set_private_key(eckey, res);

     /* pub_key is a new uninitialized `EC_POINT*`.  priv_key res is a `BIGNUM*`. */
     if (!EC_POINT_mul(group, pub_key, res, NULL, NULL, ctx))
       printf("Error at EC_POINT_mul.\n");

     EC_KEY_set_public_key(eckey, pub_key);

     char *cc = EC_POINT_point2hex(group, pub_key, 4, ctx);

     char *c=cc;

     int i;

     printf("public key : ");
     for (i=0; i<130; i++) // 1 byte 0x42, 32 bytes for X coordinate, 32 bytes for Y coordinate
     {
       printf("%c", *c++);
     }

     printf("\n");

     BN_CTX_free(ctx);

     free(cc);

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash if you've got some kind of input binary value which you need to convert to a key.

You can use a hash as input for a private key. To convert it you should first convert it to a number and then perform a calculation modulo `n` on it, where `n` is the order of the ECC domain parameters. The resulting value can be called `s` Then you can calculate the public key out of it by performing `s * G`, i.e. point multiplication with the base point.

OpenSSL is not a low level crypto library, so you'd have to program it, possibly using the OpenSSL API and the BN (big number) library that comes with it. It is not *that* tricky, but if you're still talking about 128 characters instead of 64 bytes then you may have a lot of learning to do.

Comment: No, I'm not going to provide a code sample, try yourself first.